# Find whether any possible combination exists for the following:

Tags: algorithm

I am given *N* numbers, *n*<sub>1</sub>, *n*<sub>2</sub>, *n*<sub>3</sub>, *n*<sub>4</sub>, …, *n*<sub>*N*</sub> (all being positive). Finally I am given a number *K* as input.

I am asked if it is possible to find some possible combination over *n*<sub>1</sub>, *n*<sub>2</sub>, …, *n*<sub>*N*</sub> such that the sum equals *K*, i.e. find coefficients *a*, *b*, *c*, …, *n* such that:

> *a*·‍*n*<sub>1</sub> + *b*·‍*n*<sub>2</sub> + … + *n*·‍*n*<sub>*N*</sub> = *K*

where *a*, *b*, *c*, …, *n* may assume any integral value from 0 to *K*.

We just need to find out whether such a combination exist.

What I have been thinking is placing limits over the extreme values of *a*, *b*, …, *n*. For example, *a* can be bounded as: 0 ≤ *a* ≤ floor(*K*/‍*a*). Similarly, defining ranges for *b*, *c*, …, *n*. However, this algorithm eventually turns out to be O(*n*<sup>*n*-1</sup>) in the worst case. 
Is this problem similar to Bin Packing problem? Is it NP complete?

Please help me with a better algorithm (I am not even sure if my algorithm is correct!!).

Comment: I even tried finding some discussions over problems of this kind, but couldnt find 1.. If this is a duplicate, please let me know!

Comment: Are n1, ..., nN all positive?

Comment: @isbadawi - I don't think this is exactly the subset sum problem. That doesn't allow for multiplicities, and does allow for negative numbers. @Gumbo - I assume that "an1" means "a times (n sub 1)".

Comment: n1, n2, .. nN are all positive numbers.

Comment: Edited the question to make it more clear :)

Answer (score 0):

**This solution supposes that the numbers n1, n2, ... nN are integers** (or that they have a "smallest common divisor")

---

I've got a O(K*N) algorithm (thanks to missingno for the correction). The idea is a bit of dynamic programming, a bit of the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Begin by creating a list L of K+1 booleans. `L[i]` is true if you can "build" the number i (more on that later). All values of L are initialised as `false`, except `L[0]==true`

Begin with you first number n1. For every value of i between 1 and K, check if `L[i-n1]==true`. Of course, if `i-n1<0`, then do as if `L[i-n1]==false`. If `L[i-n1]==true`, then change `L[i]` to `true`. Now, you have `L[n1]==true`, `L[2*n1]==true`, `L[3*n1]==true` ...

What does L mean now? L represent the numbers in [0..K] that can be built with only n1. If `L[K]==true`, congratulations, there is a solution built with only n1!

Take the number n2, and do the same. For every value of i between 1 and K such that `L[i]==false`, check if `L[i-n2]==true`. If it's the case change `L[i]` to `true`.

What does L mean now? L represent the numbers in [0..K] that can be built with n1 and n2. If `L[K]==true`, congratulations, there is a solution built with only n1 and n2!

If after filling L with all you N values `L[K]==false`, there is no solution to your problem.

---

The problem with dynamic programming is that it's always a problem to retrieve the solution once you've proven that there exists one... You need another list S such that `S[i]` describes what are the coefficients needed to "build" i. (exists only if `L[i]==true` of course)

Comment: This is not a polynomial algorithm, since K can be an exponentially big number.

Comment: @missingno : Oops, I corrected the complexity, it is O(K*N)... In fact, it's even O(K*M) where M is the smallest number of numbers n1..nM necessary to find a solution.

Comment: It is just as easy to retrieve a solution as it is to determine if it exists. Just remembeer to store the solutions as well instead of only storing booleans in the table.

Answer (score 0):

This is just another variant of the [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) (see the unbounded knapsack section) and is just as NP-complete and hard as the other versions.

Of course, if K is small you can use the dynamic programming solution and if N is small exaustive search works well also.

Comment: In a reduction, how would you account for the upper bound on the weight/volume?

Comment: Well, since everything here is NP complete, there is *bound* to be a (not necessarily efficient) reduction :)
But for the real problem, you can add extra numbers, in a power of 2 scheme for a direct reduction. So by using a combinations of {i, i*2, i*4, i*8, i*16} you can represent exactly all multiples of i up to 31*i - In the end you only need to add at most N*log(K) numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This is an integer program, so if you have access to a solver, I'd recommend you profile its performance and see if it works for you.